# c++ const on a collection

Tags: c++

I was surprised when the declaration:

```
const std::map<double, Foo*> myCollection;
```

would not allow me to call non-const methods on Foo*.  I thought the const applied to the collection itself (i.e., no items could be added or removed).  I would think the way to convey item const would be:

```
std::map<double, Foo const*> myCollection;
```

It seems the const in the first code snippet is distributive to the contents of the map instead of my assumption of applying only to the collection.

Am I missing something here?  It seems counter-intuitive.  How can I call non-const methods on the Foo* objects in the first declaration?

Comment: Could you please post the operation that failed and the error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be doing something wrong -- `operator[]` on `std::map` is not declared `const`, so it cannot be used to access elements of the map.  The reason it's not `const` is because if the key isn't present in the map, it gets added to the map with a default-constructed value, and doing so modifies the map.

Instead, use the `find` method to get an iterator.  The returned iterator cannot be used to modify the map, but it can be used to modify the objects which are pointed to by the values.  For example, the following code compiles and outputs `4`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<int, int*> Map;

void foo(const Map& m)
{
  Map::const_iterator i = m.find(0);
  (*i->second)++;
}

int main(void)
{
  Map x;
  int y = 3;
  x[0] = &y;
  foo(x);

  std::cout << *x[0] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `std::map` is declared as `const`. You are likely only to get `const iterators` out of it.

You also can't use `[]` on a `std::map` because that returns a reference to the map element, which means you could modify it - thus it is a compiler error.

To add to your question though, `std::map`constifies its key type anyway: `std::map<double, Foo*>::value_type` is `std::pair<const double, Foo*>`. If you add a `const` to the key type, `const const double` will simply collapse to `const double`.